# Magento hints without activating the admin developer hints

Tags: magento

I once saw a tutorial where the developer could access the magento template hints without making it live in the website, but simply by adding up some code after the url directly in the browser. Somehow I lost that code or track of the video.

How can I access Magneto hints without making them live in the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default there is no option in magento for this....

you need to install magento template paths hints extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html for this , if you already  installed this extension , go to **system > configuration** and you scroll down , you can see `MAGEPSYCHO EXTENSIONS` , once you click on that you can see as below image  [image]

if access code is "toy" ,  you can add this : **?tp=1&code=toy** after site url

Comment: Many thanks Php Beginner for your fast reply. I believe I tried his access code in my url at the time and worked without any extensions, but I might be wrong. I'll try this instead. Many thanks for your help and enjoy the rest of the day ;0)

Comment: for my knowledge default magento dont support, may be you can wait for some time, so if  others have any idea they will reply.... @user2928174